# Makro defined at beginning of row is only available in first column

Tags: latex

I am trying to create a new environment where I can add different rows, where each row contains a short makro:

```
\documentclass{report}

\newenvironment{test}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
  }
  {
    \end{tabular}
  }

% function to add rows
\newcommand\row{%
  \def\type{4}
  cell 1: \type & 
  cell 2: \type \\
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
  \row
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this gives an "undefined control sequence" error and the makro is not available in the second column:

[image: rendered table]

How can makros be available in the whole row?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341916/command-to-continually-add-to-table-with-a-command-macro/341925#341925

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for the pointer, though this is a completely different way of adding content to tables that would completely kill my current system ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution following https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195747/using-in-macro-abstracting-a-tabulars-row. It's as simple as replacing def with gdef (minding that the definitions are now global):

```
\documentclass{report}

\newenvironment{test}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
  }
  {
    \end{tabular}
  }

% function to add rows
\newcommand\row{%
  \gdef\type{4}
  cell 1: \type & 
  cell 2: \type \\
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{test}
  \row
\end{test}

\end{document}
```